# C# how to check that writes are finished in directory

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I have a filewatcher setup on a folder. Everytime a subfolder is created, an event is raised in which i want to proceed and do some stuff with the files in that new folder. Problem is, there are X number of files are been copied / generated into the new folder and i dont want to execute the rest of the code until I know that no more new files are generated within a reasonable amount of time, lets say 30 secs.

Here is some pseudo code of that i am trying to do:

```
void fsw_Created(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e) //Event 

handler for directory created
{
        //Wait until no new file activity in the newly created for 30 secs
        //Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to have a file created handler also, and use it to detect when all the files have finished writing to the new directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **System.IO.DirectoryInfo** which contains **LastWriteTime**.

You can use it as following:

```
handler for directory created
 {
         string YourFolder = @"D:\CPT\Folder\"; // just en example
         DirectoryInfo di1 = new DirectoryInfo(YourFolder);
         DateTime dt1 = di1.LastWriteTime; // that is your base folder write time
         Console.WriteLine(dt1);
         Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch(); //it's from System.Diagnostics
         sw.Restart();
         int secondWithoutAccess = 0;
         do
         {
           if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds > 1000)
           {
           //You must create new instance of Directory info every second
           DirectoryInfo di2 = new DirectoryInfo(YourFolder);
           DateTime dt2 = di2.LastWriteTime;
           Console.WriteLine(dt2);
           //if your base lastWriteTime is lower than 
               if (dt2 > dt1)
               {
                   secondWithoutAccess = 0;
                   dt1 = dt2; // You must write last write time to proper compare
               }
               else secondWithoutAccess++;
           sw.Restart(); // in all cases You restart timer
           }
         }
         while (secondWithoutAccess < 30);  // when 30 sec without access
         Console.WriteLine("Files in folder didn't change for more than 30 sec");

        // do rest of Your stuff here
    }
```

Comment: You can just call [`directoryInfo.Refresh()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.refresh(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of creating a new instance. You may also want to review your variable names.

Comment: Do event handlers start in a separate thread?  Will it work if new folders are created concurrently or do i need to put in the event handler in a background worker?